# Route to vue file from Laravel Jetstream Inertia

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I'm trying to setup a route inside Laravel Jetstream using Inertia. The route should be /bloglist.

the vue file is located in /resources/js/Blog/BlogList.vue

the route I am using is:
`Route::inertia('/bloglist', 'BlogList');`

When I open the route I get a blank page and an error

**Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Cannot find module './BlogList.vue'**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolveComponent is set in the app.js. I don't believe it can be changed per route.  You can, however, add resources/js/Pages/Blog/BlogList.vue and call it with

```
Route::inertia('/bloglist', 'Blog/BlogList');
```

Example app.js

```
new Vue({
    render: (h) =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
            },
        }),
}).$mount(app);
```

Comment: Key line being resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,   That is the path Inertia will be looking for.

Comment: Yeah, I was up for a very long time and had a "derp" moment. Thanks for pointing that out!